# Simple EXPECT script to execute remote command and displat output

Tags: ssh, expect

I am trying to connect to a network router and execute `show status` on it. 
Currently i am using:

`spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@192.168.20.254

expect " * ? password:*\r"

send -- "secretPassword\r"

sleep 5

send -- "show status\r"

sleep 10

send -- "exit\r"`


It dosen't work, i get stuck at `admin@192.168.20.254's password:`i've tried entering the password but it does not work, i get:

`server1:~# secretPassword

-bash: server1: command not found

server1:~#`
What am i doing so wrong here ... ?

Comment: I think you're just missing a suitable timeout see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try doing it like this

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 120
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@192.168.20.254
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "secretPassword\r"
sleep 5
send -- "show status\r"
sleep 10
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```

If your device is slow to respond you probably need to set a suitable timeout.

Comment: that was it. the "set timeout 120" :) thank you so much !

Answer (score 2):

First you should look at automating the whole process of collecting and tracking router information using [RANCID](http://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/) instead of doing a one off solution.

For this particular issue, take a look at [autoexpect](http://blog.rackwire.com/2010/05/using-expect-and-autoexpect-to-automate-tasks-in-linux/) to automate the creation of your expect script.  That should give you a working expect script to start from.  To fix your existing script, try running expect with the `-d` argument.  That will show you exactly what expect is looking to match, and should hopefully tell you what is wrong in your match expression.

Comment: RANCID is not up to the job as it only monitors current configuration and i want to get some information regarding current bandwidth usage with this and then save it into a dv. (i can not use SNMP)

Comment: Ok... but does my suggestion to use autoexpect and/or `expect -d` help?

Comment: i tried with <code>expect -d</code> and it worked... but no error message showed, after the sugestion from Iain to use <code>set timeout</code> it al works great now !